# EXCEL ADD PICTURE VBA WEB DYNAMICALLY GENERATED

Tags: image, excel, vba, dynamic, import

Is there a possible way of getting Excel to import a picture into a worksheet from a web location where the web location is not a simple url to a file but a dynamic page that generates the picture from the information supplied in the url?

I'm using the shapes.addpicture method at the moment and I get error 1004 - file not found. It works with: http://www.andyross.net/images/heide_hut.jpg

But it doesn't work with:
http://charts.moneyam.com/Chart.aspx?Provider=EODIntra&Code=RBS&Size=900&Skin=GreenRed&Type=3&Scale=0&Cycle=DAY1&Span=MONTH3&OVER=EMA%2812%29;EMA%2826%29;SR;AreaBB%2826,2%29&IND=MACD%2826,12,9%29;SlowSTO%2812,3,3%29;ADX%2812%29;VOLMA%2812%29&Layout=2Line;Default;Price;HisDate&XCycle=&XFormat=

The above URL would work if I put it in the browser address bar, and would produce a gif image of the stock chart for RBS.

At first I thought it was the long file name, so I used Tinyurl to produce a url short enough to be acceptable to Excel. However, it still doesn't work (and using tinyurl for the simple url does work in excel) so I think it must be the dynamic content.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd probably be better off using an embedded webbrowser control. This video can step you through setting it up and using it http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GBAHJSfm8Xg

Comment: Thanks very much! Once I got the webbrowser working it worked like a charm - Now I can import stock charts directly to my spreadsheet!